How to do change of variables in this case?
I tried to do a change of variables but made a few mistakes. I couldn’t find it out.
I let $u=xy$, $v=x+y$, computed the Jacobian as $\frac{v}{v^2-4u}$
It was wrong when I tested it with an integral.
(25/10 edited)
I found a mistake in @user170231 ‘s help.
But the result is still not true.
My attempt:


The Jacobian determinant is incorrect, and probably because you're juggling all these $\pm$ signs. Just choose one sign for $x$ and the other sign for $y$, you'll end up with the same (unsigned) determinant either way.

@user170231 I’ve chosen minus sign for x and plus sign for y. If you know the correct Jacobian and how to obtain that, please tell me.

Did you try calculating  the Jacobian of $u,v$ with respect to $x,y$? Also, the limits of integration are going to involve some very nontrivial consideration!


Look over your simplification of the determinant. You should have ended up with

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac1{\sqrt{v^2-4u}} & \dfrac{\sqrt{v^2-4u}-v}{2\sqrt{v^2-4u}} \\
-\dfrac1{\sqrt{v^2-4u}} & \dfrac{\sqrt{v^2-4u}+v}{2\sqrt{v^2-4u}}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\implies \lvert \det J\rvert = \frac{\sqrt{v^2-4u}+v}{2(v^2-4u)} + \frac{\sqrt{v^2-4u}-v}{2(v^2-4u)} = \frac1{\sqrt{v^2-4u}}$$

As for the integral, the limits you determined are also incorrect. Let $A$ denote the square $[-2,-1]\times[0,1]$, whose boundaries are the lines $x=-2$, $x=-1$, $y=0$, and $y=1$. Under your change of coordinates, we have e.g.
$$\begin{align*}
x=-2 = \frac{v-\sqrt{v^2-4u}}2 \implies v+4 &= \sqrt{v^2-4u} \\
\implies u+2v&= -4
\end{align*}$$
Similarly,
$$\begin{align*}
x=-1 &\implies u+v=-1 \\
y=0 &\implies u=0 \\
y=1 &\implies u-v=-1
\end{align*}$$
and these four lines define the boundary of a new region $B$ that is not a rectangle, like you suggest in your $u,v$-integral.

